# How to show AdMob app open ads using Swift language?

Tags: ios, swift, admob

Before, I used AdMob's banner ad in an iOS app. Now, I want to show its latest released open app ads. I checked the relevant web page of AdMob ([enter link description here](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/app-open-ads)), but the examples on this page are all in OC language. I am not familiar with OC language. Can anyone provide guidance in Swift language?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

OC code here: https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/app-open-ads

All code below goes to `AppDelegate.swift`

Import `GoogleMobileAds`:

```
import GoogleMobileAds
```

In class definition add `GADFullScreenContentDelegate`:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GADFullScreenContentDelegate {
```

Add two variables:

```
var appOpenAd: GADAppOpenAd?
var loadTime = Date()
```

Add these three functions:

```
func requestAppOpenAd() {
    let request = GADRequest()
    GADAppOpenAd.load(withAdUnitID: "YOUR_ADUNIT_ID",
                      request: request,
                      orientation: UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait,
                      completionHandler: { (appOpenAdIn, _) in
                        self.appOpenAd = appOpenAdIn
                        self.appOpenAd?.fullScreenContentDelegate = self
                        self.loadTime = Date()
                        print("Ad is ready")
                      })
}

func tryToPresentAd() {
    if let gOpenAd = self.appOpenAd, let rwc = self.window?.rootViewController, wasLoadTimeLessThanNHoursAgo(thresholdN: 4) {
        gOpenAd.present(fromRootViewController: rwc)
    } else {
        self.requestAppOpenAd()
    }
}

func wasLoadTimeLessThanNHoursAgo(thresholdN: Int) -> Bool {
    let now = Date()
    let timeIntervalBetweenNowAndLoadTime = now.timeIntervalSince(self.loadTime)
    let secondsPerHour = 3600.0
    let intervalInHours = timeIntervalBetweenNowAndLoadTime / secondsPerHour
    return intervalInHours < Double(thresholdN)
}
```

Finally call `tryToPresentAd()` from `applicationDidBecomeActive()`:

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    self.tryToPresentAd()
}
```

That's it.

Edit: Added the need to import `GoogleMobileAds`

Comment: Thanks to @Mikrasya, I have successfully used the app open ad unit ID for testing to display the app open ad of testing, but when I switched to my app open ads unit ID, the ad was not filled even waiting for 3 days. I'm in mainland China. I want to know whether it is a common phenomenon in China? or is it an individual problem with my AdMob account?

Comment: What can I do if applicationDidBecomeActive not calling?

Comment: Same problem. :(

Comment: If applicationDidBecomeActive is not being called and you are using SceneDelegate, you should add this bit of code in there instead of in AppDelegate

Comment: Thanks. 1 question though, is this the same effect with setting Frequency capping for apps.? And which one is the best practice? I ask because I'm checking which way is best for my iOS app.

Answer (score 4):

Along with Mikrasya and TripleTroop answers and if you need to show open ads from SceneDelegate you can use instruction below:

All code below goes to `SceneDelegate.swift`

Import GoogleMobileAds:

```
import GoogleMobileAds
```

In class definition add GADFullScreenContentDelegate:

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate, GADFullScreenContentDelegate {
```

Add variable:

```
var appOpenAd: GADAppOpenAd?
```

Add these functions:

```
    func requestAppOpenAd() {
    let request = GADRequest()
    GADAppOpenAd.load(withAdUnitID: "YOUR_ID",
                      request: request,
                      orientation: UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait,
                      completionHandler: { (appOpenAdIn, _) in
                        self.appOpenAd = appOpenAdIn
                        self.appOpenAd?.fullScreenContentDelegate = self
                        print("Ad is ready")
                      
                      })
    
}

func tryToPresentAd() {
    if let gOpenAd = self.appOpenAd, let rwc = UIApplication.shared.windows.last?.rootViewController {
        gOpenAd.present(fromRootViewController: rwc)
    } else {
        self.requestAppOpenAd()
    }
}

func ad(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd, didFailToPresentFullScreenContentWithError error: Error) {
    requestAppOpenAd()
}

func adDidDismissFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) {
    requestAppOpenAd()
}

func adDidPresentFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) {
    print("Ad did present")
}
```

And now we can change `sceneDidBecomeActive` function to call open ads:

```
   func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
    self.tryToPresentAd()
    // Called when the scene has moved from an inactive state to an active state.
    // Use this method to restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) when the scene was inactive.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Along with Mikrasya answer, in order to load another ad in case of ad fail or dimiss you gona need to call below functions as well

```
func ad(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd, didFailToPresentFullScreenContentWithError error: Error) {
    requestAppOpenAd()
}

func adDidDismissFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) {
    requestAppOpenAd()
}

func adDidPresentFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) {
    print("Ad did present")
}
```